# Getting a handle on Object Properties through Link Templates in AutoCAD from SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, properties, autocad

I have searched high and low for some help regarding AutoCAD Link Templates.

I have managed to create a connection between AutoCAD and my SQL server. I am able to view the servers tables from AutoCAD.

My next task is to find a way to create a link between the properties of an Object in my drawing (eg. The text of a Label) to a row in my SQL table, To the point where I could change the value of that row in SQL, and it would change the text value of the object within my AutoCAD.

Like I said i am struggling to find sources of information or any help at all with achieving this. Which is why I am here now asking if anyone could give me and help or advice with how I would achieve this.

Anything is appreciated, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I know links are looked down on but a very brief Google search (link AutoCAD and database) brought back a LOT of relevant links.  Here's the first one, directly from Autodesk: [About Database Links and Link Templates](http://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/AutoCAD-Core/files/GUID-05A3DDF8-1928-4146-9DA0-F72747B41E39-htm.html)

Comment: The Autodesk web pages are a good source of information, unfortunately they don't provide much detail or go into depth about what you can do with the Link Templates etc after the Link is created. They are more of a basic overview.

Comment: That's probably the most your'e going to find.  Autodesk added the ODBC linking in but never really progressed with it.  The real database linking was dedicated to connecting with spatial databases and shape files (Civil/Map).

Comment: Ahh I see, Is there an alternative way of doing what I am trying to achieve, do you know?

Comment: @Danny I haven't used Autocad in a few years (Map 3d 2012 I think was the last version I used) but I did linking back then. The way link templates (used to) work was you would link an item to a record and then it would show the database information when you viewed the object's properties and this link would persist when you exported a drawing for something like Autodesk Mapguide. To extract data from the database to use on the drawing, I remember I had to write relatively complex custom AutoLisp commands.